# How to get source properties on button click inside list view ? [Andorid Appcelerator]

Tags: android, listview, events, button, appcelerator

I have listview with button inside the items. I have set a click event function but it don't return clicked button properties. In iOS it works fine.

```
    var item = {
    properties : {
        accessoryType: Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_NONE,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE
    },
    events: {
       click: eventFunction
    },
    childTemplates : [
    {
        type : 'Ti.UI.Button',
        bindId : 'bindButton',
        properties : {
            width: 70,
            height: 70,
            image: "/images/user_icon.png",
            borderRadius: 35,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#dedede',
            zIndex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            idButton : 10
        }
```

When I click on button in eventFunction I expect to find e.source.idButton but e.source don't contain it. Why? In iOS I find the properties as expected.
I have tried moving events param inside the button template but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

in my listview I'm only listening to the "itemclick" event.
So my current code is something like this:

```
listView.addEventListener('itemclick',function(e){
    var item = listView.getSections()[0].getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
    if(e.bindId === 'blockIcon'){
        //do my stuff
    }
```

Let me know if this helps you

Comment: Hi and thanks for your message. In my case it's not works because I have n buttons generated dinamically and to get property for each click is necessary to know which button I have clicked.